# VBA Work Sheet change Function not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to have one cells function update every-time the user changes a specific cell range, using V.B.A.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("A6").EntireRow
    If Intersect(R, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        R.Cells(7, 4).Value = Date
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This simply is not working. I've messed with it for quite some time and cant get it to work.

Auto Calculate is on.

Macros are enabled.

It is not a shared work book.

I placed the code into Sheet1 not Module1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I closed Excel and re-opened it and this started working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved by restarting Excel

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with a similar problem, `Application.EnableEvents` should be used wisely. What I suspect happened in your case was that you set `Application.EnableEvents = false` in your code, and then either stopped debugging in the middle of it or it threw an error.

When this happens, `Application.EnableEvents` stays `false` and will stay like that until you enable it via VBA or restart Excel.

One way to prevent this is by using `On Error GoTo <Label>:` and then setting a label at the end of your code to turn events back on, ensuring that if the code borks then events will be re-enabled.

```
On Error GoTo Finally:

<code here>

Finally:
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

As per I understood, you are trying to change the data of range "D7" to current date when you change range "A6", is that right?

If yes you can do this type of change by replace all code above by:

```
Target.Offset(1, 3).Value = Date
```

Where Offset is telling to go down 1 row and 3 columns.

Now if you want to change the date of current row in column "D" do.

```
Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = Date
```

And please don't do anything with:

```
Application.EnableEvents
```